# Dependency problems in Linux

Tags: linux

I try to install a software for a thermal camera, but it gives the error message:

```
    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg -i /media/pi/PETI/libirimager-1.1.7-i386.deb
Selecting previously unselected package libirimager.
(Reading database ... 112361 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libirimager-1.1.7-i386.deb ...
Unpacking libirimager (1.1.7) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libirimager:
 libirimager depends on libudev-dev (>= 1.0).
 libirimager depends on gcc (>= 4.6).
 libirimager depends on build-essential (>= 1.14.18).
 libirimager depends on cmake (>= 2.6).

dpkg: error processing package libirimager (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libirimager
```

I tried the `dpkg --configure -a` , but did not solve the problem.
The linux is totaly new for me, so I am unfamiliar with these orders.
(Raspbian Jessie, i386)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
apt install -f
```

or install all dependencies and try again.

Comment: How can I install all dependencies? Are they independent files? I'm sorry for the silly questions...

Comment: `apt install libudev-dev gcc build-essential cmake`

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

> $ sudo dpkg -i /media/pi/PETI/libirimager-1.1.7-i386.deb

Not the best command ... No dependencies will be installed. Please do :

```
$ sudo gdebi /media/pi/PETI/libirimager-1.1.7-i386.deb
```

... Which will also install the available dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Now it is better, but I have still a message: 'This package is uninstallable' 'Dependency is not satisfiable: libudev-dev (>= 1.0)

Comment: Please edit your question to include OS name, version, architecture. This command will reply with i686 or x86_64 : `uname -m`

Comment: `libudev-dev`, Jessie : libudev-dev_215-17 ... seems to be "later than 1.0". https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libudev-dev >>> arm64 https://packages.debian.org/jessie/arm64/libudev-dev/download